# Graphite Aggregation Rules for finding per-day metrics using per-hour metrics

Tags: logging, graphite

I am facing problem regarding writing aggregation rules for plotting per-day metrics. I have two servers which are sending metric name as

> production.email.server_1.total_emails_sent.1h.sum
>   production.email.server_2.total_emails_sent.1h.sum

They are sending this metric once per hour. I am able to find the sum of these two metrics by adding an aggregation rule as follows:

production.email.all.1h.sum (3600) = sum production.email.*.1h.sum

Now I have to find the sum on per-day basis by using the same per-hour metric. I want a metrics named

> production.email.server_1.total_emails_sent.1d.sum

which I can find by summing the metric `production.email.server_1.total_emails_sent.1h.sum` for the past 24 hours. How can I find out this metric?

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like  you want the **summarize** function.

`&target=summarize(production.email.server_1.total_emails_sent.1h.sum, "1day")`

Check out the [docs for summarize](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.summarize).

Depending on how that works out, you might even like to try the [smartSummarize](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.smartSummarize) function...